# How to skip built-in functions in MATLAB debugging?

Tags: matlab, debugging

When I set a break point for debugging, the cursor "penetrates" through function `angle` and checks the corresponding code too. How can I force the cursor to only scan my code?
The weird thing is it doesn't do so for the functions `sum` or `abs`
Thanks

Comment: `step` instead of `step in`! http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-192

Comment: @Dan that's not exactly a good enough solution.  Sometimes you want to step into code that uses these files, i.e. `MyClass(angle(H), param2);`

Comment: @KronoS then use `step out` ?

Comment: @Dan again, it's frustrating to have these classes/scripts automatically debugged.  Instead of taking the extra 'steps' and having to figure out where the heck I am instead of the file that I thought I was going to be in, it'd be nice if we could skip that all together.

Comment: @Dan Thank you! BTW how can I skip certain parts of the code?

Comment: @PooyaM I'm not sure what you mean... you could just use a second break point and then press continue?

Comment: @Dan Yes. But Can it do that automatically?

Comment: I wouldnt use it myself, but perhaps you can hack something together by writing a "shortuct" in the IDE which starts by stepping into the code `dbstep in`. It then inspects the current stack with `dbstack` and if the current function resides in `toolboxdir`, you step out: `dbstep out`

Comment: @PooyaM Please be specific about what code you want to skip? I can't see a reason to do it automatically, I mean the whole point of debugging to me is to slowly work through the code looking for errors... so clicking step out is hardly the end of the world

Comment: @Dan You're right. But there are many for loops in the code and I'm sure they are correct. I just wanted to skip these loops in debugging and see the result at once...

Comment: @PooyaM yes so then make another breakpoint after the loops, and hit continue. You can't have it anymore automatic than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer as to why commands like abs and sum are automatically skipped is because they are compiled, proprietary MATLAB functions that don't actually have any readable MATLAB code with them. If you do edit('angle.m') (maybe without the m, I forget) you will see the code (as expected). Now do the same for sum, and you will notice there is no MATLAB code there, just comments. The core MATLAB functions, like sum, but also like clc and close are all core embedded functions so we can't see the code.

As was mentioned earlier in the comments, the debugger has tools that allow you to just step instead of step in, and if you are stepped in one part, you can always step out to the function calling the one you are currently looking at. Also, to skip a couple lines of code at a time, the "run to cursor" can be incredibly useful!

[More details can be found in the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-192)

Comment: fyi they are called `builtin` functions. You can use: `which -all funcname` to see what type it is (the `-all` arguments returns all overloaded versions. You could be more specific with: `which sum(1)` that way MATLAB shows the one for that specific syntax)

Comment: The function [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) can also be useful if you just want differentiate between `builtin` functions and M-files. For example, the following anonymous functions might be useful `isbuiltin=@(s)exist(s,'builtin')==5;` or `ismfile=@(s)exist(s,'file')==2;`. Note that the second one won't detect `mex` files or p-files, etc., but `exist` (`which` too) can check for those as well.